# combining two selects next o each other, not on top of the other

Tags: mysql, merge

I have this structure in my MySQL database:

```
   +--------------+    +--------------+
   |    table_1   |    |    table_2   | 
   +----+---------+    +----+---------+  
   | id |   name  |    | id | surname |  
   +----+---------+    +----+---------+  
   | 1  | tbl1_1  |    | 1  | tbl2_1  |  
   | 2  | tbl1_2  |    | 2  | tbl2_2  |   
   | 3  | tbl1_3  |    | 3  | tbl2_3  |  
   +----+---------+    +----+---------+
```

I need a query that returns this:

```
   +----+---------+---------+
   | id |   name  | surname |
   +----+---------+---------+
   | 2  | tbl1_2  | tbl2_2  |
   +----+---------+---------+
```

I searched in google, what I found is UNION which does this:

```
   +----+---------+
   | id |  name   |
   +----+---------+
   | 2  | tbl1_2  | 
   | 2  | tbl2_3  |
   +----+---------+
```

which is not what I look for. I need they are combined next to each other, not on top of each other.

Comment: can you give an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use an [**JOIN**](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp), the type of join based on your requirement.

```
SELECT id,name,surname FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 on table_2.id=table_1.id WHERE table_1.id = 2
```

The INNER JOIN will select all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the id columns we are matching on i.e the ids exist in both the tables

Comment: nope, it just selects all rows, I need to also apply a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

this is what has to be done :

```
SELECT table_1.id, name, surname FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id = 2 AND table_2.id = 2
```